# Datatable .row(0).data() is undefined on init

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I've created a datatable as such:

```
var table = $('#table1').DataTable( {   
        "ajax": "tabledata.txt",
    } );
```

However, if I want to get the first row of the table on init like so

```
var firstRow = table.row(0).data();
```

it shows `undefined`.

And

```
console.log(table.row(0))
```

gives me `_Api [0: Array(0), context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ, draw: ƒ, …]` where the first `0: Array(0)` shows

```
0: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Normally this one should not be 0 but 1.

I am guessing it is about the order of when the table is populated with ajax data and when this function is being called. Because I am able to get the data when I click on the table row

```
$('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var oneRow = table.row( this );
        console.log(oneRow)
}
```

This gives me `_Api [Array(1), context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ, draw: ƒ, …]` where the `Array(1)` gives:

```
0: Array(1)
0: 0
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How should I get the first row of data on init?

Comment: You guess is right. If data is not loaded you can not retrieve any of it. You can add the first object in your tabledata.text to a variable in the JavaScript file and use it until the rest of the data loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you guess it right. Untill `Datatable` is initialise and loaded your `dtable` is just a `var`.

If you still want to get values on load. You can try it in `fnInitComplete` or `initComplete` depending on dattable evrsion you are using something like this

```
var dtable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
        var column = dtable .row(0).data();
        alert(column[0]);
    }
});
```

More [detail here](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnInitComplete)

```
var dtable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        var column = dtable .row(0).data();
        alert(column[0]);
    },
});
```

More [Detail here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)